# Solidity public or external function - Which is more gas efficient?

Tags: solidity, remix, gas

Is using a public function access modifier more gas efficient than using a external function access modifier?

I've been running a few tests with the contact below and have gotten varying results. It also appears to differ based on the order of which I call the inc functions.

Here is the contract I'm testing this with, I've been using Remix IDE to run and have gotten varying results:

```
contract Storage {
    uint256 number;

    function incP(uint256 i) public {
        number = number + i;
    }

    function incE(uint256 i) external {
        number = number + i;
    }
}
```

Edit:

```
Using the code below and running it via Remix.
calling the public function costs: execution cost   2415 gas
calling the external function costs: execution cost 2437 gas
```

Updated code block:

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.2 <0.9.0;

contract Storage {
    uint256 number = 5;

    function incP() public view returns(uint256) {
        return number;
    }

    function incE() external view returns(uint256) {
        return number;
    }
}
```

So given this there is clearly a difference between using public or external function modifier. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 3):

Using external functions instead of public does not affect gas.

Up until `solidity 0.6.9`, only external functions allowed calldata arguments.

Public functions forced the use of the more expensive memory arguments. This means that `external` functions were more gas efficient than `public` ones.

From `0.6.9` onwards all functions can use memory and calldata. This means there is now no gas difference.

Comment: It sounds like the takeaway from this is to prefer `calldata` over `memory`, for gas efficiency

Answer (score 1):

Let's see, you should create 2 contracts StorageP and StorageE.

```
contract StorageP {
    uint256 public number;

    function inc(uint256 i) public {
      number = number + i;
    }
}

contract StorageE {
    uint256 public number;

    function inc(uint256 i) external {
      number = number + i;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind: The first storage slot call is more expensive than the next calls.

Answer (score 1):

Tangential to the other answers that say `external` costs the same gas as `public`: Function order matters, due to some low-level stuff that concerns variable storage access. (The later a function is defined, the more gas it costs (very slightly)). If you want to find out the gas cost of a function use `gasleft`:

```
function abc() public view returns (uint gas) {
    gas = gasleft();
    // do stuff
    gas -= gasleft();
    return gas; // this line can be omitted as solidity will auto-return named return variables.
}
```